# Find swapped nodes in BST

Tags: java, tree

A BST has two nodes swapped. Figure out which two nodes.
Looking for code-review, optimizations and best practices.

```
public class SwappedNodes {

    private TreeNode root;

    SwappedNodes(List<Integer> items) {
        create(items);
    }

    private void create (List<Integer> items) {
        if (items.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The item is empty");
        }
        root = new TreeNode(items.get(0));

        final Queue<TreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
        queue.add(root);

        final int half = items.size() / 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < half; i++) {
            if (items.get(i) != null) {
                final TreeNode current = queue.poll();
                int left = 2 * i + 1;
                int right = 2 * i + 2;

                if (items.get(left) != null) {
                    current.left = new TreeNode(items.get(left));
                    queue.add(current.left);
                }
                if (right < items.size() && items.get(right) != null) {
                    current.right = new TreeNode(items.get(right));
                    queue.add(current.right);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private static class TreeNode {
        private TreeNode left;
        private int item;
        private TreeNode right;

        TreeNode (int item) {
            this.item = item;
        }
    }

    private static class PrevNode {
        private TreeNode prevNode;
        PrevNode (TreeNode prevNode) {
            this.prevNode = prevNode;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the 2 nodes which if swapped results in binary search tree.
     */
    public int[] getSwappedNode( ) {
        final List<TreeNode> list = new ArrayList<>();
        computeSwappedNodes (root, new PrevNode(null), list);

        int[] result = {list.get(0).item, list.get(list.size() - 1).item};
        return result;
    }


    private void computeSwappedNodes (TreeNode node, PrevNode prevNode, List<TreeNode> list) {
        if (node == null) return;

        computeSwappedNodes (node.left, prevNode, list);
        if (prevNode.prevNode != null) {
            if (prevNode.prevNode.item > node.item) {
                list.add(prevNode.prevNode);
                list.add(node);
            }  
        } 

        prevNode.prevNode = node;

        computeSwappedNodes (node.right, prevNode, list);
    };
}


public class SwappedNodesTest {

    // both values in different branches
    @Test
    public void testDifferentBranches() {
        SwappedNodes sn1 = new SwappedNodes(Arrays.asList(10, 4, 25, 2, 20, 8, null));
        int[] a1 = {20, 8};
        assertArrayEquals(a1, sn1.getSwappedNode()); 
    }

    // parent child relationship
    @Test
    public void testParentChild() {
        SwappedNodes sn3 = new SwappedNodes(Arrays.asList(10, 2, 20, 5, 8, 15, 29));
        int[] a3 = {5, 2};
        assertArrayEquals(a3, sn3.getSwappedNode());
    }

    @Test
    public void testAncestor() {
        SwappedNodes sn4 = new SwappedNodes(Arrays.asList(8, 5, 20, 2, 10, 15, 29));
        int[] a4 = {10, 8};
        assertArrayEquals(a4, sn4.getSwappedNode());
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this an assignment from geeksfromgeeks?

Answer (score 3):

```
computeSwappedNodes (root, new PrevNode(null), list);
```

Unneeded space between function name and parentheses with arguments. You do this multiple times.

```
/**
 * Returns the 2 nodes which if swapped results in binary search tree.
 */
public int[] getSwappedNode( ) {
```

No, you return the items stored within. Not the nodes. **You don't fulfill the assignment as stated.** Additionally, you return multiple nodes, so name the method `getSwappedNodes`. Lastly, no need for a space in an empty set of parentheses.